# prevent to get Id field/Field label

Tags: schema, label

All Fields label are getting in this list but i don't want ID field from below code  how to avoid ID field label.

```
public List<String> AllLabels{get;set;}
 String type='Account';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {

 System.debug('##Field API Name='+fieldName);// list of all field API name
 AllLabels.add(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `how to avoid ID field label`, do you want to filter out lookup fields; or get rid of Id from label such that `Account Id` becomes `Account`

Comment: I am getting this error if i bind ALLLabels List on vf page  Could not resolve field 'Record ID' from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!sobj[headerApiName]}' in page CongiProMiles

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), could you please share a minimum version of code for someone to look and help you further. The code and information you've provided in the question is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> if i bind `ALLLabels` List on vf page Could not resolve field 'Record ID' from `<apex:inputField>` value binding '`{!sobj[headerApiName]}`' in page `CongiProMiles`

I'm pretty sure what's happening is this:

1. You're creating a `List<String>` of all of the field labels on an object, in the code you've shown us in your question.
2. You are attempting to iterate over that `List` to create `<apex:inputField>` components bound to the actual field values on an sObject instance.

The issue, then, is that you're trying to access field values by subscripting their *labels*, not their *API names*. "Record ID" is the label for the field whose API name is `Id`. You can't ask an sObject for its "Record ID" field; you must specify the API name.

You need to be using API names anywhere you're doing value binding. If you also want to display the field label, you may need to create additional data structures to map the API name to the label so Visualforce can access it.

Comment: yes, alernate option is creating fieldset and use on the visualforce page